# Results of recursion grouped in list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, recursion, functional-style

I made a recursion where I should plot resulting points. When I do `Print[point1]`, it just gives me result:

```
{300, 100}

{333.333, 100.}

{366.667, 100.}

{350., 71.1325}

{300, 100}

{400., 100.}

{433.333, 100.}
```

etc. I wonder if there is a way to collect this inside the code so the result is

```
list = {{300, 100}, {333.333, 100.}, {366.667, 100.}, {350., 71.1325}, {300, 100}, {400., 100.}, {433.333, 100.}};
```

I had to use `AppendTo` inside my code also. Please don't do any really hard coding on this since it's a school project.

EDITED :

```
kochKriva[p1_, p2_, n_] := 
 Module[{x1, x2, y1, y2, angle, p3 = {}, p4 = {}, p5 = {}},
  x1 = p1[[1]];
  x2 = p2[[1]];
  y1 = p1[[2]];
  y2 = p2[[2]];

  angle = N[Pi/3];
  AppendTo[p3, N[(2*x1 + x2)/3]];
  AppendTo[p3, N[(2*y1 + y2)/3]];


  AppendTo[p4, N[(2*x2 + x1)/3]];
  AppendTo[p4, N[(2*y2 + y1)/3]];

  AppendTo[p5, 
   p3[[1]] + (p4[[1]] - p3[[1]])*Cos[angle] + (p4[[2]] - p3[[2]])*
     Sin[angle]];
  AppendTo[p5, 
   p3[[2]] - (p4[[1]] - p3[[1]])*Sin[angle] + (p4[[2]] - p3[[2]])*
     Cos[angle]];
  If[n > 0, 
   {
    kochKriva[p1, p3, n - 1];
    kochKriva[p3, p4, n - 1];
    kochKriva[p4, p5, n - 1];
    kochKriva[p5, p2, n - 1];
    }, ListLinePlot[{p1, p3, p5, p4, p2}]
   ];
  Return[ListLinePlot[{p1, p3, p5, p4, p2}]] (* This should be returned, but the result is next image *)
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use `Print`. Construct your list with `NestList`, `FoldList`, or `Table`. Cannot say any more because you did not show any code.

Comment: @MarcoB I edited with complete code included. I was looking at c++ code and turned it into mathematica as close as I could.

Comment: you showed the function but did not show example of how to call it.

Comment: @Nasser kochKriva[{30,10},{60,10},3] .This is to get third iteration of Koch's curve. n is number of iterations, p1 and p2 are points of the line that is used. I didn't plan on it to go more than the fourth iteration, it should be enough.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear, what is it you want to return back to the caller. What list is it? p3? p4? p5? it is not clear. You show a list there. But we do not know what that list mean in your code. or is it `{p1,p2}` ?

Comment: @Nasser they should all be returned because I need to use points of all the lists to plot with them. This is just a starting code, it could be changed to match what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to generate Koch curves on your own. Here I provide my version:

```
Clear[myKochPoints]
myKochPoints[n_] := Module[{pts0 = N[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], iterate, mat},
  mat = {{2, 1}, {1, 2}}/3;
  iterate = 
   x \[Function] {x[[1]], 
       Sequence[#, RotationTransform[π/3, #][#2], #2], 
       x[[2]]} & @@ (mat.x);
  Nest[Join @@ BlockMap[iterate, #, 2, 1] &, pts0, n]
  ]
```

[image]

However, why not directly use the built-in [`KochCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KochCurve.html)?

---

**Update: What is implemented in the codes**

From the beginning, one has two endpoints: $ P_1: (x_1, y_1) $ and $ P_2: (x_2, y_2) $ (the collection of which two is denoted `x` in the codes), and in one cycle one obtain five (three more) points as the result through:

1. Find their two trisection points $ P_3 $ and $ P_4 $ (implemented by the `mat.x`, two more points now, and suppose the order: $ P_1, P_3, P_4, P_2 $);
2. Rotate $ P_4 $ by $ \pi/3 $ about $ P_3 $ to get $ P_5 $;
3. Finally the resultant five points are: $ \{P_1, P_3, P_5, P_4, P_2\} $ (`iterate` in the codes realizes this mapping: $ \{P_1, P_2\} \rightarrow \{P_1, P_3, P_5, P_4, P_2\}$).

For the 2nd-order cycle, the process is the same, but with new pairs of initial endpoints obtained from the above 1st-order five points: $ P_1 $ and $ P_3 $, $ P_3 $ and $ P_5 $, $ P_5 $ and $ P_4 $, and $ P_4 $ and $ P_2 $.

And so on (`n` in the codes means $ n $th-order).

Comment: This does solve the problem, but my task is to use recursions, that's why I can't use the built in. I have to create recursion that plots the Koch curve.

Comment: @me995 OK, then you might be interested in my `myKockPoints`.

Comment: I haven't done such advanced mathematica, so I kind of have trouble with this code. Can it be simplified somehow?

Comment: @me995 I do not think the present version is the simplest but for the moment I am not able to optimize it. However, I can explain what the codes are doing, or say what clue of thought has lead to those codes.